# clear checkboxes of selected options in jquery multiple select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, multiple-select-query

In below fiddle, I have a bootstrap modal and there is a Select Users MultipleSelect.

I need to clear the selection on modal close, like set the dropdown to defaults without any selection.

For example, if I select user 1 and user 2, then on modal close, none should be selected. The previous selection must be gone.

The code I am trying isn't helping me out and neither are any posts here on stack overflow.

A little that I tried is this :

```
$("#usersDropDown option:selected").attr("checked",false);
```

And this :

```
$("#usersDropDown option:selected").attr("selected",false);
```

And also this:

```
$("#usersDropDown option:selected").removeAttr("checked");
```

Please guide me what should I do ?

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5m966drd/1/)

Comment: `.prop("selected", false)`

Comment: that doesn't work either

Comment: are you using loudev multiselect plugin?

Comment: try this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/5m966drd/3/)

Comment: does not work, thanks anyway for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code to reset the form data and the multi select box in the drop-down on bootstrap modal window to clear contents.

```
$('#shareLocationModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
    $('#usersDropDown').multipleSelect('refresh'); // to reset the multi select users dropdown
    $(this).find('form')[0].reset(); // To reset form fields
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Hi can you check now [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pt657c8k/). Its working I guess. 
I add this code to modal shown. If you want you can add it to hidden function

```
$("#usersDropDown").siblings(".ms-parent")
 .find("li.selected input[type='checkbox']").click();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$('#usersDropDown').multipleSelect("uncheckAll");` inorder to deselect all.
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5m966drd/4/)

```js
var currentDate = new Date();
var day = currentDate.getDate();

if (day < 10)
  day = "0" + day;

var month = currentDate.getMonth() + 1;
if (month < 10) {
  month = "0" + month;
}
var hours;
var year = currentDate.getFullYear();
todayDateReport = year + "-" + month + "-" + day;
$("#currentDate").html(todayDateReport);
startDate = todayDateReport + " 00:00:00";
endDate = todayDateReport + " 23:59:59";
hours = " 00:00";

$('.input-group').datetimepicker({
  format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm',
  collapse: true,
  sideBySide: false,
  useCurrent: false,
  showClose: true,
});
 $('#hoursInput').datetimepicker({
             format: 'HH:mm',
            collapse:true,
    sideBySide:false,
    useCurrent:false,
    showClose:true,
    focusOnShow: false,
   });
   $('#hoursInputExpiry').datetimepicker({
             format: 'HH:mm',
             collapse:true,
    sideBySide:false,
    useCurrent:false,
    showClose:true,
    focusOnShow: false,
   });
$("#startDateInputExpiry").val(startDate);
$("#endDateInputExpiry").val(endDate);
$("#hoursInput").val(hours);
$("#hoursInputExpiry").val(hours);

$("#sendDropDownOptions").on('change', function() {
  if ($("#sendDropDownOptions option:selected").text() == "Datetime") {
    $("#durationHoursSend").addClass('hide');
    $("#sendTD").append($("#startdatetimeSend"))
    $("#startdatetimeSend").removeClass('hide');
  } else if ($("#sendDropDownOptions option:selected").text() == "Hours") {
    $("#startdatetimeSend").addClass('hide');
    $("#sendTD").append($("#durationHoursSend"))
    $("#durationHoursSend").removeClass('hide');
  } else {
    $("#startdatetimeSend").addClass('hide');
    $("#durationHoursSend").addClass('hide');
  }
});

$('#shareLocationModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {

$('#usersDropDown').multipleSelect("uncheckAll");

  if ($("#expiryDropDownOptions option:selected").text() == "DatetimeExp") {
    $("#startdatetimeExpiry").removeClass('hide');
    $("#expiryTD").append($("#startdatetimeExpiry"))
  }
});
$("#expiryDropDownOptions").on('change', function() {
   if ($("#expiryDropDownOptions option:selected").text() == "HoursExp") {
    $("#startdatetimeExpiry").addClass('hide');
    $("#durationHoursExpiry").removeClass('hide');
    $("#expiryTD").append($("#durationHoursExpiry"))
  }else if ($("#expiryDropDownOptions option:selected").text() == "DatetimeExp") {
    $("#durationHoursExpiry").addClass('hide');
    $("#startdatetimeExpiry").removeClass('hide');
    $("#expiryTD").append($("#startdatetimeExpiry"))
  }
  else {
    $("#durationHoursExpiry").addClass('hide');
    $("#startdatetimeExpiry").addClass('hide');
  }
});

$("#usersDropDown").multipleSelect({
  placeholder: "Select Users",
  selectAll: true,
  width: "100%",
  filter: true,
});

$("#send").on("click", function()
        {
                $("#sendDropDownOptions").val('Now').trigger('change');
        });
```

```css
.modal-body {
  max-height: calc(100vh - 210px);
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://rawgit.com/wenzhixin/multiple-select/master/multiple-select.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasny-bootstrap/3.1.1/css/jasny-bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment-with-locales.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    
  
    
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    
  
    
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
  
    
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasny-bootstrap/3.1.1/css/jasny-bootstrap.css">
    
  
    
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasny-bootstrap/3.1.1/js/jasny-bootstrap.js"></script>
    
  
    
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.45/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
    
  
    
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/multiple-select/1.2.0/multiple-select.js"></script>
    
  
    
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://rawgit.com/wenzhixin/multiple-select/master/multiple-select.css">


<button class="btn btn-primary btn-responsive md-btn" id="btnn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#shareLocationModal">
  Share
</button>

<div id="shareLocationModal" class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog wideModal">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header modal-header-custom">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="modaltitle">Share Location Preferences</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
              <div class="form-group col-md-12 col-sm-6">
                <form id="shalreLocationDetails" class="form">
                  <div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label>Phone No:</label>
                      <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="phoneNo" data-toggle="tooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="" data-original-title="Phone No" onkeypress="return checkValidation(event)" data-placement="bottom" placeholder="Mobile Number"
                      maxlength="10" data-validation="number">
                      <!-- <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone"placeholder="Phone No" data-validation="number"  data-validation-allowing="+" /> -->
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label>e-mail:</label>
                      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="" data-original-title="e-mail" placeholder="e-mail" data-validation="email">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label>Select Users:</label>
                      <select id="usersDropDown" multiple="multiple" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="" data-original-title="Select Users">
                        <option>User 1</option>
                        <option>User 2</option>
                        <option>User 3</option>
                        <option>User 4</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label>Send:</label>
                      <select id="sendDropDownOptions" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="" data-original-title="Send Options" class="form-control" style="width:100%;">
                        <option value="Now">Now</option>
                        <option value="Datetime">Datetime</option>
                        <option value="Now">Hours</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>

                    <div id="sendTD"></div>
                    <br>

                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label>Expiry:</label>
                      <select id="expiryDropDownOptions" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="" data-original-title="Expiry Options" class="form-control" style="width:100%;">
                        <option>DatetimeExp</option>
                        <option>HoursExp</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>

                    <div id="expiryTD"></div>
                    <br>
                  </div>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-responsive md-btn" id="send">Send</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-responsive md-btn" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="startdatetimeSend" class="hide">
  <div class='input-group date' id='startDate'>
    <input type='text' class="form-control" placeholder="Start Date" id="startDateInputExpiry" />
    <span class="input-group-addon">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="durationHoursSend" class="hide">
  <div class='date' id='startDate'>
    <input type='text' class="form-control" placeholder="Start Date" id="hoursInput" />
    <span class="input-group-addon">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>


<div id="startdatetimeExpiry" class="hide">
  <div class="input-group date" id='endDate'>
    <input type='text' class="form-control" placeholder="End Date" id="endDateInputExpiry" />
    <span class="input-group-addon">
                               <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="durationHoursExpiry" class="hide">
  <div class='date' id='startDate'>
    <input type='text' class="form-control" placeholder="Start Date" id="hoursInputExpiry" style="position: relative;" />
    <span class="input-group-addon">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @AshishBahl You are welcome, and I think this is the proper way to do unchecking for the plug-in you are using. http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/multiple-select/docs/#checkall-uncheckall

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `$("#usersDropDown").prop('selectedIndex',-1);` ?

Answer (score 0):

Works for me:

```js
$("input:checkbox").removeAttr("checked");
```